# Why can't exception handlers in mips overwrite registers?

Tags: assembly, mips

The reason that I have read is that the program could be using those registers and we do not want to lose the values that they hold. But, in that case we could write previous values on to the stack as we usually do in function calls. What's wrong with that?

Edit: Registers apart from $k0, $k1 of course!

Comment: Yeah, I understand that the program cant predict when exceptions will occur. But, why cant the exception handler itself save all the registers on the stack and restore them before returning irrespective of whichever register was actually being used by the main program?

Comment: what happens if the stack pointer moves onto a new page, causing a page fault?

Comment: Actually since I'm taking the computer architecture course at present, I had this doubt. We haven't been taught page faults as yet, so I couldn't imagine scenarios arising from corrupted stack pointers. The answer provided by user2684957(which I believe even you are talking about) seems to be reasonable. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other registers can be used but they have to be stored in the global memory. A possible reason for entering the interrupt handler may be because of an exception caused by a corrupted stack-pointer. Hence, registers are saved in a statically allocated global memory.